# iOS Logout design

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an app that has many web services and notifications going on.  I need a logout feature.  I wish there was a way simply to kill the app and restart it but there is not.  Does anyone have some recommended guidelines on creating a logout function (it will take the user back to the login screen).  The problem is there are notifs that should be unsubscribed from, views that should be removed, view controllers that I want to be released, then everything to reinitialize.  That seems like a lot of work for a simple task.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to make sure when terminating all requests is to change all delegates that are supposed to receive responses to nil. After you've taken care of this, you should indeed remove all irrelevant view controller's views from your root view (and release them if they are retained anywhere), and of course flush any existing data you don't need. If you design your MVC elegantly, you can achieve these actions without a lot of fuss, for example a ScreenManager Singleton class that manages all your view controllers should have no problem taking you back to the login screen while releasing any other view. A DataManager Singleton class that holds various data collections should have no problem removing any unneeded data entities and so on...

Comment: I see. That was the route I was heading (and yes my app is set up as you described with singleton services), I just wanted to make sure I was not doing anything out of the ordinary. Thanks!

Comment: @Stavash Can you explain the purpose of a ScreenManager type class, and where I could find more information on how to set up my app in this "elegant" way?

Comment: I actually don't have an example I'm at liberty to share but generally there are two possible approaches: 1. Subclass NSObject and have a singleton class that holds references to the current active controller, to any active alert, nav controller, etc and manage screen navigation from there. 2. Subclass UIViewController such that you have sort of a screen manager for each main flow (which has a root controller). Hope this helps.